# can't install gnome 3.4 extension?

Tags: gnome

so I try to install the extension from
http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-gnome-shell-36-and-gnome-shell.html

but when I try this in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i gs-extensions-extensions-common_3.4.deb
```

I get this:

```
    dpkg: error processing gs-extensions-extensions-common_3.4.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gs-extensions-extensions-common_3.4.deb
```

I dont know what happenned the previous steps worked fine(I guess)

so anyone know how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: `No such file or directory`: you need to change to the directory where that file is or run it with the correct path. Example: `sudo dpkg -i /home/my_username/path/to/gs-extensions-extensions-common_3.4.deb`. Also you can just double click it on Nautilus: the Software center will allow you to install the package.

Comment: but unfortunately I dont know whre the file is downloaded to. Sorry I don't understand commands. Could you tell me where its would be downloaded?